# nav hover not working in ie

Tags: html, css

Doing a school project - http://harden6615.com/project2/site/about.html - and noticed in IE that my nav hover padding is off. It works fine in all other browsers but in IE the background color is also pushed to the left slightly. Anyone see what wrong from the link?

```
header ul a:hover, header ul li a.current {
    background-color: #79ADAF;
    padding: 5px 6px 0px 40px;  
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you referring to?

Comment: IE is still back in supporting HTML 5 :)

Comment: i think my laptop uses ie9. @dev - is this a html5 issue or a css issue. seems like some css that's not working all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for the whole `/*nav*/` section in your css and it should work in IE:

```
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;   
}

header {
    font-family: 'SansationLight';
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #EDEAE1;
    width: 250px;
    height: 312px;    
}

#logo {
    margin:10px auto;
}

#logo img{
    margin:0px auto;
}

header ul {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right:40px;
    padding-top:40px; /*the space between the image and links*/
}

header ul li a{ 
    color: 000;
    padding: 5px;  
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header ul a:hover, header ul li a.current {
    background-color: #79ADAF;
}
```

Comment: though this might help, it doesn't give me the look I was going for. I like the bar going all the way to the left edge but I want a little more space between each link bar so I'll have to keep playing around with what you've posted.

Comment: for spaces between links, edit the top and bottom _margin_ of `header ul li a`. currently, it has none.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked on ie. Slight problem is in ie the text and the bar is centered. In everything else, the text is slight raised too high. Haha one of the reasons why I love flash is at least you get the consistency and compatibility. But this does work for me.